# Back button to execute previous function

Tags: java, jquery

I have got a webpage with a few functions on it to load different content dynamically into the content section. What I want to achieve is by pressing back button to execute last/previous function. At the moment it goes to the previous page. Is it possible to do without hash tags in the URL bar as well? Seems like create a history of function list. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the **session**.

Note that there is a plugin named **JQuery session plugin**, available from [here](https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin)

Tutorials links :

[Lassosoft](http://www.lassosoft.com/Tutorial-Understanding-Cookies-and-Sessions)
[weschools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Comment: Is it possible to do with jquery or Java somehow?

Comment: yes ofcurse, try to use this plugin, its a JQuery session plugin:

https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin

Comment: So if I click on the back button how it should look like? Sorry for stupid question.

Comment: Don't worry brother, try to understand this plugin, take your time to understanding it and im sure that you shall find the answer!